# Loading rds from Dropbox links using readRDS( )

Tags: r

I have been using `readRDS(gzcon(url("my dropbox links")))`for a long time to load my saved .rds field from Dropbox without any issues. But ever wonder why `readRDS("my dropbox links")` does not do the same thing. I got an error like

```
    Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

It seems like a fair, simple question, but I couldn't figure it myself. Many thanks in advance~

Comment: Incidentally, you can remove the unnecessary `gzcon` call: just `readRDS(url(…))` works.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks for that, yep. later after posting I found that the `readRDS(url(…))` indeed also worked~

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my previous comment seems to have been removed. To recap, I’m *guessing* that there’s no good reason that this doesn’t work: it’s just that nobody bothered to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative would be to first download the file and then read the RDS:

```
download.file("https:www.somesite.com/somefile.rds",
              "data.rds", 
              method = "curl")
```

The readRDS - function checks if the argument is a connection and but doesn't create URLS itself:

```
> readRDS
function (file, refhook = NULL) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) {
        con <- gzfile(file, "rb")
        on.exit(close(con))
    }
    else if (inherits(file, "connection")) 
        con <- if (inherits(file, "url")) 
            gzcon(file)
        else file
    else stop("bad 'file' argument")
    .Internal(unserializeFromConn(con, refhook))
}
<bytecode: 0x5648012c7c50>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

therefore the url - function is needed.

```
> link<-"https://www.google.com"
> inherits(link,"connection")
[1] FALSE
> link2<-url("https://www.google.com")
> inherits(link2,"connection")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: youre right readRDS should accept a connection

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the `readRDS( )` function. The reason I store the dataset in Dropbox is for working across different computers for the same project. The `download.file()` looks a nice options too~

Comment: no problem, take a look at github, it may be also suited to store your data. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/06/data-on-github-the-easy-way-to-make-your-data-available/